# How to append list to list using python?

Tags: python, list

I wonder to append listB to listA

**input**

```
listA = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
listB = [[g,h],[i,j]]
```

**wondering output**

```
sum_list = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h],[i,j]]
```

under my code, Please find something to fix.

```
    for line in vcf_file:
    match = []
    CHROM = line.split('\t')[0]
    POS = line.split('\t')[1]
    REF = line.split('\t')[3]
    ALT = line.split('\t')[4]
    VEP = line.split('ANN=')[1].split('|')[1]
    ANN = line.split('ANN=')[1].split(';')[0]
    if len(ANN.split(',')) > 1 :
        for i in ANN.split(','):
            GENE, HGVS = i.split('|')[3], i.split('|')[10]
            for one in GENE:
                tmp=[]
                tmp.append(sampleNo)
                tmp.append(GENE)
                tmp.append(CHROM)
                tmp.append(POS)
                tmp.append(REF)
                tmp.append(ALT)
                tmp.append(VEP)
            match.extend(tmp)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

---

**Thank you for answering.**
I resolve the problem.
I made another list and extended it. It's solved.

```
    for line in vcf_file:
    match = []
    CHROM = line.split('\t')[0]
    POS = line.split('\t')[1]
    REF = line.split('\t')[3]
    ALT = line.split('\t')[4]
    VEP = line.split('ANN=')[1].split('|')[1]
    VEP_impact = line.split('ANN=')[1].split('|')[2]
    REF_DP = line.split('\t')[9].split(':')[1].split(',')[0]
    ALT_DP = line.split('\t')[9].split(':')[1].split(',')[1]
    AF = line.split('\t')[9].split(':')[2]
    ANN = line.split('ANN=')[1].split(';')[0]
    if len(ANN.split(',')) > 1 :
        for i in ANN.split(','):
            GENE, HGVS = i.split('|')[3], i.split('|')[10]
            ann = []
            for one in GENE:
                tmp = []
                tmp.append(sampleNo)
                tmp.append(GENE)
                tmp.append(CHROM)
                tmp.append(POS)
                tmp.append(REF)
                tmp.append(ALT)
                tmp.append(VEP)
                tmp.append(VEP_impact)
                tmp.append(REF_DP)
                tmp.append(ALT_DP)
                tmp.append(AF)
            ann.extend(tmp)
        match.extend(ann)
```

Comment: Did you already do any research how to do this?

Comment: I did..
The code I made doesn't work the way I want it to, so I ask..

Comment: `tmp` is inside the for loop. Put it before the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways atleast to do this in python.

You can use the `extend()` or the `+` operator.

Eg.

```
listA.extend(listB)
```

Or

```
listA+=listB
```

Answer (score 1):

`listA.extend(listB)` should work, but it modifies the original `listA`. If you want `sum_list` to be a different list, you can copy it first with something like

```
sum_list = list(listA)
sum_list.extend(listB)
```

Comment: With this approach the inner lists are still the same. You'll need [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to prevent this.